# AngularJS - what are the major differences in the different ways to declare a service in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on an angularJS app and I am trying to stick with the most efficient and widely accepted styles of development in AngularJs. 
Currently, I am using this way of declaring my services like so:

```
app.factory('MyService', function() {
  /* ... */
  function doSomething(){
     console.log('I just did something');

  }

  function iAmNotVisible(){
      console.log('I am not accessible from the outside');
  }
  /* ... */

  return{
     doSomething: doSomething
  };
});
```

However, there are numerous examples out there and I am not quite sure which design style to follow. Can someone with extensive knowledge about services explain the reason why a certain style is more relevant than another?

Is what I am doing useful in any way other than restricting the access to certain functions in my service?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you layout your `factory` or `service` as they do in the [angular-seed app](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), except that app annoyingly only uses `value` in the `services.js` boilerplate. However you can adapt the layout they use for controllers, directives and filters.

```
'use strict';

/* Filters */

angular.module('myApp.filters', []).
  filter('interpolate', ['version', function(version) {
    return function(text) {
      return String(text).replace(/\%VERSION\%/mg, version);
    }
  }]);
```

Which means for a service you would do:

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

angular.module('myApp.filters', []).
  service('myservice', ['provider1', 'provider2', function(provider1, provider2) {
      this.foo = function() { 
          return 'foo'; 
      };
  }]).
  factory('myfactoryprovider', ['myservice', function(myservice) {
       return "whatever";
  }]);
```

This has more boilerplate than you absolutely need, but it is minification safe and keeps your namespaces clean.

Than all you have to do is decide which of `const`, `value`, `factory` or `service` is most appropriate. Use `service` if you want to create a single object: it gets called as a constructor so you just assign any methods to `this` and everything will share the same object. Use `factory` if you want full control over whether or not an object is created though it is still only called once. Use `value` to return a simple value, use `const` for values you can use within `config`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an accepted standard but I myself follow this convention:

```
var myServiceFn = function (rootScope, http) { ... };
...
app.factory('MyService', ['$rootScope', '$http', myServiceFn]);
```

I feel like this is cleaner than defining the function inline and also allows for proper injection if I ever decide to minify my files. (see http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).

Comment: where are you defining myServiceFn? if you define it outside, wouldn't that make it global?

Comment: After injecting it into the app, you could follow with a `var myServiceFn = null;` But yeah, why define it outside to begin with if the goal is to keep it private.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I've been defining services within modules like so:

```
angular.module('userModule', [])
  .service('userService', function() {
    this.user = null;

    this.getUser = function() {
      return this.user;
    };

    this.userIsNull = function() {
      return (this.user === null);
    };

    this.signout = function() {
      this.user = null;
    };
  })
```

I think it is more clear to use the .service rather than the .factory?

Comment: Remeber that `service` and `factory` do different things, so it isn't just down to which is clearer. `factory` is called like a normal function, `service` is a constructor called with the `new` operator.

Comment: @Duncan, yes agreed.  I find that the service is more "service" like?  For instance, when you inject to the module into the app, you only get one service, like a singleton object?  The factory I use when I want a "factory", i.e. most of my factories only have a single create() function that returns a new object.  Often the service call a factory to create new objects for it.  I'm still somewhat new to AngularJS, so I may be getting caught up in the design pattern terms and not the AngularJS terms.