# AngularJS Service Passing Data Between Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

When using an AngularJS service to try and pass data between two controllers, my second controller always receives undefined when trying to access data from the service. I am guessing this is because the first service does a $window.location.href and I'm thinking this is clearing out the data in the service? Is there a way for me to change the URL to a new location and keep the data persisted in the service for the second controller? When I run the code below the alert in the second controller is always undefined.

**app.js (Where Service is Defined)**

```
var app = angular.module('SetTrackerApp', ['$strap.directives', 'ngCookies']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) 
{
$routeProvider
  .when('/app', {templateUrl: 'partials/addset.html', controller:'SetController'})
  .when('/profile', {templateUrl: 'partials/profile.html', controller:'ProfileController'})
  .otherwise({templateUrl: '/partials/addset.html', controller:'SetController'});
});

app.factory('userService', function() {
var userData = [
    {yearSetCount: 0}
];

return {
    user:function() {
        return userData;
    },
    setEmail: function(email) {
        userData.email = email;
    },
    getEmail: function() {
        return userData.email;
    },
    setSetCount: function(setCount) {
        userData.yearSetCount = setCount;
    },
    getSetCount: function() {
        return userData.yearSetCount;
    }
};
});
```

**logincontroller.js: (Controller 1 which sets value in service)**

```
    app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, $window, userService) {

$scope.login = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/login',
        data : $scope.user
    }).success(function (data) {
        userService.setEmail("foobar");
        $window.location.href = '/app'
    }).error(function(data) {
        $scope.login.error = true;
        $scope.error = data;
    });
}
});
```

**appcontroller.js (Second controller trying to read value from service)**

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $http, userService) {

$scope.init = function() {      
    alert("In init userId: " userService.getEmail());
}

});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Define your service like this

```
app.service('userService', function() {
  this.userData = {yearSetCount: 0};

  this.user = function() {
        return this.userData;
  };

  this.setEmail = function(email) {
        this.userData.email = email;
  };

  this.getEmail = function() {
        return this.userData.email;
  };

  this.setSetCount = function(setCount) {
        this.userData.yearSetCount = setCount;
  };

  this.getSetCount = function() {
        return this.userData.yearSetCount;
  };
});
```

Check out Duncan's answer here:

[AngularJS - what are the major differences in the different ways to declare a service in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933321/angularjs-what-are-the-major-differences-in-the-different-ways-to-declare-a-se)

Comment: Thanks @Josh-Petitt. I'm still getting undefined but I'm now thinking it's because on the second page I transition which is a full HTML document I have a ng-app directive in the html element. So I'm guessing this is what is clearing out the service data? Does that sound correct?

Comment: Maybe, its hard to say without looking at the whole app.  FWIW, here is an AngularJS project I have been working on to learn.  You might poke around the app/user directory and see how I implemented it.  I am able to use the userService on different pages. https://github.com/jpmec/done

Comment: @user1093077 Hi, Did you get the work around of your solution. I am having same problem at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118335/angular-dependency-injection-passing-values-between-modules-using-service