# How to access object from a controller inside another controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access an object from a controller inside another controller.
For example:

Controller 1

```
MyApp.controller('workController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.xList = [
    {name:'test', type:'web', link:'test', image:'iso.jpg'},
    {name:'test', type:'web', link:'test', image:'iso.jpg'},
    ];

});
```

Controller 2: How to console.log an object from controller 1?

```
MyApp.controller('projectController', function ($scope) {
    console.log('$scope.xList[1]);
});
```

I tried $scope.workController.xList[1] too but didn't work.

Please help

Comment: Checkout [rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) for a way to communicate between controllers. It can broadcast messages with data across controllers that will listen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS Service Passing Data Between Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952620/angularjs-service-passing-data-between-controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of Angular controllers is to tie together view and services. For this reason, they're not really meant to talk to each other directly.  If you need to communicate between controllers, you'd do it with a shared service.

```
MyApp.controller('workController', function($scope, SharedService){
    SharedService.set([
        {name:'test', type:'web', link:'test', image:'iso.jpg'},
        {name:'test', type:'web', link:'test', image:'iso.jpg'},
    ]);
});

MyApp.controller('projectController', function($scope, SharedService){
    console.log(SharedService.get());
});

MyApp.service('SharedService', function(){
    var self = {
        get: function(data){
            return self._data;
        },
        set: function(data){
            self._data = data
        }
    };

    return {
        get: self.get,
        set: self.set
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scope** is defined per controller... In order to share data across controller you still have the option to use `$scope.$parent` or `$rootScope` to link controllers but I would use those carefully.

Angular Services are based on singleton patterns. You can also use those to share information between controllers and I think it will be the best approach.

I found that this has been previously discussed and here are some good examples:

[AngularJS Service Passing Data Between Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17952620/1959948)