# $routerProvider pass JSON object to next controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have the following $routerProvider

```
$routeProvider.
          when('/list', {
            templateUrl: '/list.jsp',
            controller: 'ListController'
          }).
          when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: '/edit.jsp',
            controller: 'EditController'
          }).
          otherwise({ redirectTo: '/list' }
);
```

I have a ui-grid, I want to pass the selected row data from ListController to EditController. Since my selected row is a JSON object with lots of properties, I do not want to send those data through URL.

More over this ListController and EditController is being used for different data structure like {a:10, b:20} as a row. Some time {x:11, y:12, z:21} as a row some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use use a `service` in this case for passing data between controllers.

Ref: [AngularJS Service Passing Data Between Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952620/angularjs-service-passing-data-between-controllers)